# How to tell layout to space everything 50/50?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical linear layout with two ListViews. I want the top ListView to take up 50% of the screen. I want the bottom listivew to take up 50% of the screen. How can I do this in XML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following layout should work

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

How this works:

- Initially both lists have no height
- After measuring everything with a height, the remaining height (in this case all of it as there are no other views with a specified height or `wrap_content`) is divided up between all the views with no height and a `layout_weight`
- The height of each view will be `(layout_weight of View) / (Sum of layout_weights in parent ViewGroup)`
- In this case, `(Sum of layout_weights in parent ViewGroup) = 2` and `(layout_weight of View) = 1` for each `ListView`, so each `ListView` occupies `1/2` of the available space

Answer (score 2):

Set Vertical LinearLayout to have `height:fill_parent` and then set the `weight of each ListView to "1" e.g. android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: That doesn't work correctly. Weight defines how the extra space is distributed. The content will end up being 50/50 only if they are initially exactly same size.